# How to hide an app url inside a String in android

Tags: java, android, string, android-intent

I create an application which can share a message through social medias, emails , etc. In here I want to share my app url through a string . It means , when touch on this String it should go to my app in play store. Actually I want to hide my app url inside this string.

but I couldn't complete this task. Here are some steps which I followed .

```
Intent sharingIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
sharingIntent.setType("text/plain");

String shareBody = "Here is the share content body";

StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
builder.append("**** ").append("Results").append(" ****").append("\n\n");
builder.append("Value - ").append(Val).append("\n");
builder.append("Prime - ").append(Val).append("\n");
builder.append("Status - ").append(Val).append("\n");
builder.append("Ratio - ").append(Val).append("\n");
builder.append("Result - ").append(Range).append("\n");
builder.append("https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=net.mobilecraft.realbasketball&hl=en");
String text=builder.toString();

sharingIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Results");
sharingIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, text);
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sharingIntent, "Share via"));
```

How could I hide this https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=net.mobilecraft.realbasketball&hl=en inside a String .

Have any ideas ?

Thank you .

Comment: What do you mean by *hide*? Not have it be rendered as a hyperlink?

Comment: As far as i know, you can't, since the url itself is a String

Comment: If you want to hide the direct link to google play, you can use a url redirection from your server or any redirection service. So, instead of showing https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=net.mobilecraft.realbasketball&hl=en, it will show something like http://yourserver.com/something

Comment: @JonnyHenly, Actually , I want put a string in this StringBuilder as Download this app and when touch on this Download this app it should go to my app in play store.

Comment: So your talking about rendering the string `"Download this app"` to point to your app. Like how Stack Overflow can [render links like you want](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38780820/how-to-hide-an-app-url-inside-a-string-in-android).

Comment: @JonnyHenly : Yes, you are correct.

Comment: Well you'll have to see if the sites your posting to or email clients you're sending to have some type of markdown enabled that can render links like Stack Overflow's markdown.

Comment: No, you can't wrap an url inside a text. It's depends on each application how to handle the data you pass. Some application can hide the url automatically, some can't

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, you don't hide the URL inside a String. You simply pass the String. Now, on the receiving end the client application (mail client, messaging app, etc.) will themselves parse the String and show it to the user as a clickable link. Similar to how facebook is able to tell that you posted a link when you simply paste a link.

Comment: Actually , I want put a string in this StringBuilder as Download this app and when touch on this Download this app it should go to my app in play store.

Comment: Yes, that should work too. Simply, append the link to your `StringBuilder`.

Comment: I think OP is talking about [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38780820/how-to-hide-an-app-url-inside-a-string-in-android#comment64932890_38780820).

Comment: @JonnyHenly Yeah, I figured. Thats why I said AFAIK, the client applications should do what I said above.

Comment: @Barrier I was thinking what other apps do and I noticed mostly use shortened URLs, so they appear nicer.

Comment: @Shaishav :- I am also thinking about it .